# How to debug "ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED: Host 'abc' is blocked because of many connection errors" error

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, express, mysqladmin

A quick Google search returns many results for fixing this error, but from what I can tell none of them give advice on how to discover the root cause. My understanding is that it happens whenever my application reaches a limit on the number of consecutive failures when connecting to the database. However, I can't figure out a way to determine the source of these failures. Is there a way to list the failed queries or connection attempts that led to this error? Ideally I would be able to determine whether this was due to a simple network failure, bad inputs, etc.

Comment: How much RAM?  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.  There may be additional clues from the _type_ of connection error(s).

Comment: @RickJames I'll try that, thank you. This isn't my app and I'll need to request permission for devops to execute those commands.

Comment: Maybe the app keep on opening new connections? We ever experienced that some of our in-house testing apps keeps on opening new connection to our test MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

For every possible root cause, a dedicated column in table `performance_schema.host_cache` will show how many time each root cause was found.

To investigate, simply execute:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.host_cache
```

See the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/host-cache-table.html

Comment: Unfortunately this returns an empty set

Comment: There are some arcane steps to "turn on" the performance_schema.